# Xamarin.Mobile Change file path

Tags: android, xamarin, android-camera-intent

I am using Xamarin.Mobile component to take Image/ Video from default camera in Android.I am able to store and read images or videos.

My question is: This way files are stored in app's files in Android/obb folder, I need to have those files in root folder of SD card.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding ../../../../../app_folder path, so that I can get root folder and can create folder over there.